# IPv6 - country detection

Tags: mysql, ipv6

I have a CSV file downloaded from Maxmind which contains IPv6 data. I need to upload it to MySql table and then use this table to detect a country by IPv6.

So the first question is what the MySql type should be `LONGSTART` and `LONGEND` fields in my MySQL table as max INTEGER length can be of 20 while I have `42540488558116655331872044393019998208` number?

And the other question is how to build a MySql query in order to find an IP address between `LONGSTART` and `LONGEND`? I use a function( `ipv6_numeric($ip)` ) which converts `'2001::11ff:ffff:f'` IPv6 address into a long number like `2540488558116655331872044393019998208`.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Why would you use MySQL for this? Why not detect the country before inserting the row and then insert both the ipv6 and the country code?

Comment: You got me wrong, I plan to use a table with IPs and countries.

Comment: In that case, the whole thing about countries seems irrelevant. You aren't having a problem determining the country, you're just having an issue with comparing really large values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following simple SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM `geoip2`
WHERE [SEARCH IP NO] <= LONGEND LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work. I have to have 42540488558116655331872044393019998208 number in my sql table

Comment: You need to have DECIMAL(39,0) UNSIGNED type for the first two columns in the database.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `ig0my_geodata_v6` WHERE 42541956123769880606220662448000886044 BETWEEN `longstart` AND `longend`

Comment: Great! I find most of the information from FAQs https://www.ip2location.com/faqs/db1-ip-country

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it.